# Using a javascript variable from outside the function to pass through to my AJAX function

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an AJAX function which gets called every time the enter key is pressed. I have a set of javascript variables that get passed into the data of the AJAX function. Previously, these JS variables were equal to elements in the HTML (the contents of a text area). Now I want these JS variables to be equal to the values of JS variables outside the function.

```
   function stream()
{


    var line_Number = $('#lineNumber').val();
    var post_code = '#lineText';
    var post_id = $('#Streamid').val();
    if (post_code != ''){

    $.ajax({
      url: "post-code.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: {lineText: post_code, lineNumber: line_Number},
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(data){
        if(data != ''){
          $('#Streamid').val(data);
        }
        $('#autoStream').text("Sending data");
          setInterval(function(){
            $('#autoStream').text('');
          }, 100);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Another function then calls the AJAX function

And here are the JS variables which I want to access and pass into the AJAX function

```
     var text;
     var lineNumber;
     var lineText;
     var numOfSpaces;




   function update(e) {

       text = //code
       lineNumber = //code
       lineText = //code
```

I didn't show the code for each variable as I felt it might unneccesarily complicate this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you have these options:
1- Use a hidden HTML element:

```html
<input type="hidden" id="someVariable">
```

where yout want to initialize in your script (JQuery):

```
$('#someVariable').val(myVar)
```

and in script in ajax function (JQuery):

```
var myVar = $('#someVariable').val()
```

2- You know `var` scope if it is declared outside a function in javascript, is hole document (window).
3- Pass the arguments to your ajax functio. e.g:

```
function stream(firstVariable, secondOne, ...)
```

Comment: Hi, I seem to be getting problems with $('#someVariable').val(myVar). Declaring my var as this says it is undeclared and assigning the vale says Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Comment: Make sure you made the HTML input tag and also you have JQuery library include. after that make sure when you call `$('#someVariable').val(myVar)`, `myVar` has value. (it is your variable. e.g: `post_code`) If you still have problem let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can create a json array and pass it as parameter of your ajax function,
this way you avoid to write unnecessary code, example:

```
let params = {
    "line_number": $('#lineNumber').val(),
  "post_code" : '#lineText',
  "post_id" : $('#Streamid').val()
};



 function stream(params)
{
    if (params.post_code != ''){

    $.ajax({
      url: "post-code.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: data,
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(data){
        if(data != ''){
          $('#Streamid').val(data);
        }
        $('#autoStream').text("Sending data");
          setInterval(function(){
            $('#autoStream').text('');
          }, 100);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi stan Chacon. For me it says Cannot read property 'post_code' of undefined - for if(params.post_code !=' '){

Comment: I still seem to be encountering a similar problem. It says textedit.php:144 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'post_code' of undefined for if (parameters.post_code != ''){